# active record query order where first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, where-clause, ruby-on-rails-5, active-record-query

I am using c9 cloud ruby on rails and my Rails version is 5.0.0.1

I want to compose an ActiveRecord query to select the restaurant with the best rating which has not been visited yesterday. When I applied `all` `where`, `order` and `first` in the query, it throws an error. However, if I don't use `where` or `order`, it works fine.

This works:

```
restaurant1= Restaurant.order('rating').last!
@suggested_restaurants=restaurant1.name
```

This gives strange results:

```
restaurant1=Restaurant.order('rating').where{last_visit<Date.yesterday}
@suggested_restaurants=restaurant1
```

**Results:** `#<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x000000046af7f8>`

This triggered error:

```
restaurant1=Restaurant.order('rating').where{last_visit<Date.yesterday}.last
@suggested_restaurants=restaurant1
```

**Error:** `undefined method 'last' for #ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x00000004587a10>`

I can get around this issue by using `find_by_sql` but I'd like to know why and how to use `where` in Rails 5. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
restaurants = Restaurant.where('last_visit < ?', Date.yesterday).order({ rating: :asc })
```

this gives you a collection of restaurants matching your constraints passed in `where` method, the result of which is chained to `order` method that orders the collection in ascending order of the values in `rating` column of `restaurants` table. use `:desc` if you want to order in descending order.

Then, you can retrive last object with

```
restaurant1 = restaurants.last
```

Comment: The result is much better: #<Restaurant:0x00000003e1aea8>. I will go from there. Thanks!

Comment: Also, could help me understand why your "restaurants" can generate a collection while my code cannot.

Comment: you chained order method before where method.. i.e you tried to order your collection without first actually finding them

Comment: Thanks. It works now and thanks a lot! It's strange that I believed I tried something like this (where first then order) before but not worked at that time.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the `Relation` for restaurants that have not been visited today, then you can call `.last` on that.

```
restaurant1 = Restaurant.order('rating').where('last_visit<?', Date.yesterday).last
@suggested_restaurants=restaurant1
```